# check for fast window resize javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

My problem is:

In my application i have multiple handlers for the resize event, which dynamically change the sites visual appearance. Unfortunately theres no event for maximizing the browser window and on maximize my whole page ends up in a mess.

I did a small workaround with setInterval, which triggers the resize event 10 times per second. Can i somehow enhance this workaround or is there another possibility to solve my problem?

I thought about checking if the window is resized very fast and if yes trigger the resize event but it didnt work out for me. Please help :)

My code looks like this 
jsfiddle.net/3ycyzLk8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timer should be unnecessary. A regular listener works fine for maximize. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asn8vhkL/).

Code:

```
    var resizeHandler = function(){
      $("body").html($("body").html() + "<br />resized");
    }

    $(window).resize(resizeHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it doesnt work yet but on the basis of your answer i noticed that my problem is not the event not being triggered. It is probably the speed of resizing or the point in time when the event triggers. When exactly does the resize event trigger?

Comment: I don't know the exact sequence, but obviously it must be within a split second of the resize event - eg., pressing the maximize button. More info would be helpful. For example: You may have the listener placed where it is not being activated. Or there may be a downstream glitch - eg., are you using it to evaluate a div size that is changed slowly with a slider? That would result in an invalid result unless you put a timer to wait until after your slider finishes.

Comment: you literally saved my day. I just delayed the code on resize by 0.2 seconds and it works. thanks a lot!